# I need to get value of a certain Row and Column in AWK

Tags: awk

I need only to get the value of `WOX` which is just down it and it is in this Example equal 4

```
IOT  CND  FO    WZX  END
0         0     0    0
WOX  SR  POW   LIO LIO2
4    00  0
FDR   OTY  M
0
```

I tried the below code but I can't go further .

```
WOXpos=index(DATA,"WOX") 
BR=trim(substr(DATA,WOXpos,3))
```

The output that I got is as below

```
IOT
0
WOX
4
FDR
0
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Your code is incomplete. Please show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Show the expected output. Only the number below `WOX`?  Or the key and the number? Check the data of the input file. Is it correct that there seem to be missing numbers? What would be the expected output for `OTY`? Is the key `WOX` always in the first column or could it be in any column?

Comment: Can `WOX` appear more than once in the same line? If yes, what should happen in this case?

Comment: what is the column delimiter for this file? tab? fixed width? something else?

Comment: Without knowing how the input is formatted (what the field delimiter is, for example), it's pretty hopeless to answer this with any sort of authority. Why isn't the value associated with `WOX` the string `4    00`, for example?

Comment: Do you want to match a line that contains WOX or a field that is equal to WOX?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

As stated in a comment, the key `WOX` is expected in the first column only. This script assumes that the fields are separated by one or more spaces or tabs and will ignore leading spaces or tabs.

```
awk -v key=WOX 'found { print $1; found=0 }
    $1 == key { found=1 }' inputfile
```

prints

```
4
```

**Explanation:**

In `awk`, field numbers / columns start with 1. (`$0` refers to the whole line.)

- `-v key=WOX` = set variable
- `found { print $1; found=0 }` = If key was found in the prevoious line, print value from the first column and clear the flag
- `$1 == key { found=1 }` = Compare the first field and set flag in case of a match

If the key `WOX` appears in more than one line, the script will print the values below all occurrences, one per line.

---

*previous proposal*

```
awk -v key=WOX 'col { print $col; col=0 }
    { for(i=1; !col && (i<=NF); i++) if($i == key) col=i }' inputfile
```

*Explanation:*

In `awk`, field numbers / columns start with 1. (`$0` refers to the whole line.)

- `-v key=WOX` = set variable
- `col { print $col; col=0 }` = If column is nonzero, print value from this column and clear the column
- `{ for(i=1; !col && (i<=NF); i++) if($i == key) col=i }` = in a loop search for the first field that matches the key and save the column number.

If `WOX` appears more than once *in the same line*, it will print the value below the first one.

This script works with the input and key shown in the question, but will have problems if there are empty values before the key or value field.

Comment: this will only work as long as there are no blank/empty values in a line before a `WOX` value; need more input from OP as to the field delimiter ... tab? fixed width? something else?

Comment: I tried only till this point and stopped there, expected value is the value under WOX whish is 4 , T need only the number under WOX,it is ok to have missed number for other fields, WOX appeared only in the first column.

Comment: This is more clear (to my eyes): `for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i == key) {col=i; break}` -- it will be more efficient at any rate, reducing the number of iterations.

Comment: @hesham Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/757165/edit) to add clarification, don't use comments for this purpose.

Comment: @glennjackman The number of iterations is the same, but the `break` will simplify the loop condition and avoid testing the condition once more after the match is found.